# How am I supposed to configure xterm?

Tags: arch-linux, xterm, x-resources

I am trying to configure XTerm terminal and in the Wiki, it says it is done via X resources. I installed `xorg-xrdb` package then created a `~/.Xresources` file and edited and added these lines:

```
XTerm.vt100.foreground: white  
XTerm.vt100.background: black 
XTerm.vt100.color0: rgb:28/28/28  
XTerm.vt100.color15: rgb:e4/e4/e4
```

but it doesn't do anything. `xterm` still opens with its strange font and white background black text colour. What am I supposed to do here?

References:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/X_resources
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xterm

Comment: Did you load the resources (`xrdb ~/.Xresources`) or restart the display manager after editing the file?

Comment: Yes I loaded the resources and reboot the system completely after loading but it just opens the same.

Comment: "_I loaded the resources and reboot the system completely_" - if you load the resources and then reboot, you'll lose the newly loaded resources. Don't reboot. Instead, use `xrdb -merge <~/.Xresources` and then try opening the `xterm`

Answer (score 0):

Your window manager launches xterm based on settings stored somewhere in /etc probably.

grep -ir xterm /etc

I have these in my notes from years ago.

```
xterm -ls -fg green -bg black -fn 10x20 -geom 80x35
xterm -ls -fg green -bg black -fn vga11x19
xterm -ls -fg green -bg black -fn vga
```

Comment: I use i3 right now. Is there another place I should look?

Comment: @SweetScore if you use `startx`, add your `~/.xinitrc` to your question.